# background-image hidden in chrome when absolute width small than div

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image

I have a background-image in chrome that should be dynamic. It's part of a image map I'm building. In chrome however when the (absolute size of the) image is larger than that of the parent div on hover the background image just vanishes.

You can see this behaviour in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Lvv05q1w/4 (**EDIT: Changed fiddle to a simplified version**) (note this is a snippet of the real app with some features removed to make the problem hopefully more easy to identify. There must be only one image in the real app so solutions having multiple image tags which we then display/hide on hover can't be used here). If you shrink the width of the output so the end of the image is just off the page and hover over the image in ff you'll see the hover image applies. In chrome you'll see the background-image on the div just vanishes.

**Browsers Affected**

Chrome

Opera

**Browsers Unaffected**

Chromium (running on Lubuntu 14.04)

Firefox

Internet Explorer 11

Safari (tested via VM only)

Base CSS from fiddle looks like (I know I can compress into the background property but it was making it easier for me to fiddle around in chrome dev tools earlier)

```
#htmlmap_1 {
    background-image: url(http://hm25.dev.blox42.com/images/htmlmaps/branch.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: 50% 0%;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

**Screenshots of Issue**

Prehover image
[image: Prehover image]

Posthover - Chrome - The background image attached to the div has vanished - only the main image shows
[image: Posthover - Chrome - background image has vanished]

Posthover - FF Image has resized as expected and the image overlays the background image
[image: Posthover - FF Image has resized as expected and the image overlays the background image]

EDIT:
The one thing that kinda makes a difference is removing the `background-repeat:no-repeat` attribute. That gives the expected result of the image shrinking like in ff. However obviously I don't want the image to repeat itself so it is NOT a viable solution. Hopefully it might help someone with a solution tho!

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem. Could you insert some screenshots,please?

Comment: @Héctor Added some screenshots to help! Thanks for looking!

Comment: do you need to use map with js? what about only CSS?

Comment: The map is necessary for my particular use case. However even in CSS I can replicate this in http://jsfiddle.net/Lvv05q1w/4/

Comment: @dippas and probably should have mentioned the above example where i can replicate it is without the map element